# Select first instance of a set of items

Tags: mysql, select, greatest-n-per-group

I'm attempting to modify an existing query that pulls the most recent order from a set of customers and provided order_type.

The current query works fine (albeit a little slow, all columns below are indexed):

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT(td1.product_id), 
    td1.customer_id, 
    td1.date_test_added,
    tdmi.product_type_id
FROM 
    order_history AS td1
    LEFT JOIN order_history td2     
    ON td1.customer_id = td2.customer_id AND td1.date_test_added < td2.date_test_added
    LEFT JOIN order_types tdmi      
    ON tdmi.product_id   = td1.product_id 
WHERE
   td2.date_test_added IS NULL
   AND tdmi.product_type_id = 31
   AND td1.customer_id IN (91000, 91001, 91002, 91003)
```

If I change the less-than operator in the first join to greater than, no results are returned.

What is the best way to change this to pull the earliest order (based on date_test_added)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You query says:

> Pull the most recent order from a set of customers and only if that order has product with type 31.

When you change the `<` to `>` it says:

> Pull the oldest order from a set of customers and only if that order has product with type 31.

So it is possible that the modified query to return no results, even the first query, with same parameters returns something. That would happen when the oldest order has product with type different than 31.

---

If that wasn't the intention of the query but you want the most recent (or oldest) order among the orders that have a product of type 31, you need to modify it, so the `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` antijoin considers this restriction.

Some other minor notes:

- the `LEFT JOIN order_types tdmi` works as an `INNER` join really, due to the `tdmi.product_type_id = 31` condition in `WHERE`.
- `DISTINCT` is not a function. It modifies the whole `SELECT` and not just one column, so the parentheses are redundant and can only bring confusion.
- In a not so minor note, the `DISTINCT` looks suspicious. It can probably be removed.

The query becomes:

```
SELECT -- DISTINCT
    td1.product_id, 
    td1.customer_id, 
    td1.date_test_added,
    tdmi.product_type_id
FROM 
    order_history AS td1
    LEFT JOIN order_history td2   
        JOIN order_types tdmi2      
            ON  tdmi2.product_id = td2.product_id
            AND tdmi2.product_type_id = 31   
        ON  td1.customer_id = td2.customer_id 
        AND td1.date_test_added < td2.date_test_added
    JOIN order_types tdmi      
        ON  tdmi.product_id = td1.product_id
        AND tdmi.product_type_id = 31 
WHERE
   td2.date_test_added IS NULL
   AND td1.customer_id IN (91000, 91001, 91002, 91003) ;
```

Comment: The first order is type 22.   Would there be a way of excluding orders that do not have type 31 from the date comparison (short of making temp tables)?   There can be multiple types assigned to one order.

Comment: So you want the most recent / oldest order among the orders that have a product of type 31?

Comment: Why do you need the `DISTINCT` by the way? It seems redundant to me.

Comment: ypercube,  I'm looking for the oldest order for each customer_id having type 31.

Comment: I added a query. Try it with both `<` (most recent) and `>` (oldest).

Comment: The `>` works, though I needed to add back the DISTINCT since it pulled the same data across 6 rows (there are six separate order_ids for that customer).

Comment: 6 separate orders for the same date and same customer? Show us the `SHOW CREATE TABLE ..;` output for both tables. The `DISTINCT` can probbaly be removed with a proper rewrite.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73957/discussion-between-ypercube-and-a-coder).

Answer (score 1):

The code in the manual, and your version of it with

```
AND td1.date_test_added < td2.date_test_added
```

is terribly inefficient.  It is Order(N^2).  That is, as you double the number of rows, the query takes 4 times as long.

There are a few Order(N) algorithms; see the tag I added, plus go over to stackoverflow (a more suitable place for your Question) and peruse https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group . 
 For even faster code, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max .

Comment: Thanks for the answer - will investigate soon.    Is there any way  you could cross pollinate the text on  your site to here, in case your site ever goes offline?

Comment: @acoder - Not really.  There are multiple use cases; the total text probably exceeds the limit here.  I have about 20 blogs like that; they are all aimed at answering questions on forums.  Sure, the site _could_ go offline.  So _could_ stackexchange and stackoverflow.